# Установка приложения через сайт

Tags: javascript, android, html, ajax

Слышал что есть механизм установки приложения через сайт. То есть на сайте есть кнопка установить приложение, оно скачивается и появляется на мобильном устройстве практически как приложение, но является просто загруженным сайтом который отображается без оболочки браузера. Насколько знаю в таких приложениях используется Ajax, но как сделать так чтобы сайт скачивался и размещался, мне интересно) Интересует то как называется такая технология.Заранее всем спасибо Пожалуйста, в топ)

Comment: Вроде оно: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)

Answer (score 1):

Смотри, тут уже поднимался вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22167859/revisions

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию)